# Как вывести список администраторов беседы? Пишу на python с библиотекой vk api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что про vk api python чат-ботов говорят в интернете очень мало.

Я хочу выводить список Администраторов/Создателя как мне это сделать?
Пишу на python библиотека vk api

Спасибо заранее)
Вот код в которой этой функции ещё нет:

```
from random import random
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType


vk_session = VkApi(token="**********************")
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, "**********")
vk = vk_session.get_api()

def photo(id, url):
    vk.messages.send(user_id = id, attachment = url,random_id=0) 

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat:
        
            
        if event.obj.text=='!команды':
               random_id = round(random() * 10 ** 9)
               chat_id = int(event.chat_id)
               message = "да ты ***** нет у меня команд!"
               vk.messages.send(random_id=random_id,
chat_id=chat_id,
message=message)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Решить эту проблему можно с помощью метода [groups.getMembers](https://vk.com/dev/groups.getMembers).

Нам нужно передать параметр **filter** со значением **managers**

> managers — будут возвращены только руководители сообщества (доступно при запросе с передачей access_token от имени администратора сообщества).

Сделать мы можем это вот так: *(вместо event.group_id можно ввести сразу id вашего сообщества)*

```
vk.groups.getMembers(group_id=event.group_id, filter='managers')
```

Или:

```
vk.method('groups.getMembers', {'group_id': event.group_id, 'filter': 'managers'})
```

Результатом этого запроса будет подобное значение:

```
{'count': 6, 'items': [{'id': 123456789, 'role': 'editor'}, 
                       {'id': 234567891, 'role': 'administrator', 'permissions': ['ads']},
                       {'id': 345678912, 'role': 'moderator'}, 
                       {'id': 456789123, 'role': 'creator', 'permissions': ['ads']}, 
                       {'id': 567891234, 'role': 'administrator', 'permissions': ['ads']}, 
                       {'id': 678912345, 'role': 'administrator', 'permissions': ['ads']}]}
```

---

Вот код для вашей конкретной задачи, если вы хотите вернуть только id администраторов/владельца:

```
administrators = [] 

for manager in session.groups.getMembers(group_id=event.group_id, filter='managers')['items']:
    if manager['role'] in ('administrator', 'creator'): 
        administrators.append(manager['id'])
```

Comment: Лирическое отступление. В ВК называть владельца сообщества создателем не совсем правильно, потому что в соцсети с не столь давних времен предусмотрена возможность полной передачи прав на сообщество другому юзеру, т.е. создатель(creator) теряет статус владельца(owner), а другой юзер его получает. В "нормальном" ВК всё так и есть, хотя в разделе документации везде фигурирует только "creator". Хотя это логично, менять всё в API ради этого несерьёзно, наверное.